# Typescript custom type definition file does not work

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have seen thousands of answers to similar question and none of them worked for me. I am trying to use an npm module which does not have typescript type definitions by creating my own .d.ts file. I always get the following error: `Could not find a declaration file for module 'aws-elasticsearch-connector'.`

File structure

[image]

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

aws-elasticsearch-connector.d.ts

```
declare module 'aws-elasticsearch-connector';
```

index.ts

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk'
import { Client } from '@elastic/elasticsearch'
import { createAwsElasticsearchConnector } from 'aws-elasticsearch-connector'
```

Comment: Just tried this setup and the error "Could not find a declaration file for module 'aws-elasticsearch-connector'" did not appear. If the error does not appear when you run the compiler directly (`npx tsc` or `yarn tsc`), then I guess something happened with the VS Code + TypeScript integration and restarting VS Code may help. Or you can also try restarting TypeScript server in VS Code (open Command Palette and search for "TypeScript: Restart TS server")

Answer (score 0):

Could you try setting the include option in your tsconfig.json like this:

```
"include": ["src/**/*"]
```

The include option's documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include